# Odoo ORM query grouping

Tags: python, orm, odoo, odoo-10

I need to convert below query to Odoo ORM:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    (start_date < 'date' OR start_date IS NULL)
    and (end_date > 'date' OR end_date IS NULL) ;
```

I have tried below filter, but it seems to give all results:

```
filter = [
  "|",
  ("start_date", "<", date.today()), 
  ("start_date", "=", None), 
  "|", 
  ("end_date", "<", date.today()), 
  ("end_date", "=", None)
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This filter worked as expected:

```
filter = [
  "&", 
    "|",
      ("start_date", "<", date.today()), 
      ("start_date", "=", None), 
    "|", 
      ("end_date", ">", date.today()), 
      ("end_date", "=", None)]
```